# how to copy content and put it in a newly created pdf using iText

Tags: java, itext

How to copy contents from a existing pdf and put it in a new pdf with other contents

for example

> page 1-title page
>
> page 2 index
>
> page 3 [contents from another pdf]
>
> page 4 ending page

i have tried the following code

using pdfstamper i have tried but not able to do get the output

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.getUnderContent(1);
        PdfReader r;
        PdfImportedPage page;
        for (String path : EXTRA) {
            r = new PdfReader(path);
            page = stamper.getImportedPage(r, 1);
            canvas.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
            stamper.getWriter().freeReader(r);
            r.close();
        }
        stamper.close();
```

i have tried with

```
Chapter chaptertemp = new Chapter(new Paragraph(chapTitleriskassesstemp), i);
                chapTitleriskassesstemp.setLocalDestination(chaptertemp.getTitle().getContent());
                 List<InputStream> list = new ArrayList<InputStream>();


                data.getVendorValidation().forEach(data -> {
                    PdfReader  pdfReader,r;
                     PdfImportedPage page;
                    try {

                        pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileDirectory+data.getFileName());

                         PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfReader);
                            PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
                            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("a.pdf"));
                            TextExtractionStrategy strategy;
                            for (int ig = 1; ig <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); ig++) {
                                strategy = parser.processContent(ig, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
                                out.println(strategy.getResultantText());
                            }
                            reader.close();
                            out.flush();
                            out.close();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            });
                content.add(); // i don't know how to add it to the main object of pdf content

                chapterList.add(); 


            }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide some more informations.

Comment: @ReneKnop please find the code above

Comment: Is there any exception you got ?

Comment: @SyedHamzaHassan no exceptions but how to add it to document object

Comment: @MadhuNair How about preparing a PDF A.pdf with your pages 1 and 2 and one PDF B.pdf with your page 4 separately and then merging A.pdf, another PDF, and B.pdf using the iText `PdfCopy` class?

Comment: @mkl thats what i did. but not convincing ..still somehow i am managing

Comment: *"not convincing"* - Well, that's the iText API structure before version 7, strictly different classes for creating a document from scratch (`PdfWriter`), adding simple stuff to an existing PDF (`PdfStamper`), and merging multiple existing PDFs (`PdfCopy`). You could cheat a bit but the cost most likely would be decreased maintainability.

Comment: @mkl yeah agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prepared a PDF A.pdf with your pages 1 and 2 and one PDF B.pdf with your page 4 separately and then merging A.pdf, another PDF, and B.pdf using the iText PdfCopy